# Is there a way to put an entire part of a request in a SoapUI variable?

Tags: soapui, json, groovy

I'm using SoapUI to test REST webservices and I'm stuck on an issue.

I have a json object, called `coverages`, which consists of **one or more** other objects, it looks something like this (example with 2 coverages):

```
"coverages" : [
   {
   "CovNr" : 123,
   "CovDesc" : "My coverage" 
   },
   {
   "CovNr" : 456,
   "CovDesc" : "Another coverage"
   }
]
```

The thing is, sometimes there is one coverage, and sometimes there are multiple. This  means I need the coverages object to be variable, and have either one or more coverages as its body, depending on # of coverages.

Since the number of coverages isn't always the same I can't use properties for the `CovNr` and `CovDesc` attributes. Also I can't just always add like three and leave two empty if only one is used (can't have empty attributes).

I tried to set a coverages property using groovy script, which consisted of the entire body of the coverages object, but that didn't work (I'm guessing the editor can't parse an entire part of a request from a property).

Example of what I tried:

*in groovy:*

```
def coverages = "[   {   "CovNr" : 123,   "CovDesc" : "My coverage"    },   {   "CovNr" :456,   "CovDesc" : "Another coverage"   }]" 
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("coverages", coverages)
```

*in request body:*

```
...
"coverages" : "$(#TestCase#coverages)",
...
```

This didn't work.

Is there another way to add a variable number of coverages to my request body?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that your parameter is a String instead of a json object.

In your groovy code:
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

```
def backToJson = new JsonBuilder(coverages).toPrettyString();
return backToJson
```

In your request body:
grab the result of your groovy testStep like this:

${nameOfYourGroovyTestStepHeret#result}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a script to dynamically generate the "coverages" part of your request body. Instead of setting the entire "coverages" JSON as a property, you can use a Groovy script to build the JSON array based on the number of coverages needed.

For example:

def coverages = []
def numOfCoverages = 2 // replace with actual number of coverages
for (int i = 0; i < numOfCoverages; i++) {
coverages.add([CovNr: 123 + i, CovDesc: "Coverage " + (i + 1)])
}
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("coverages", coverages.toString())

And in your request body:

...
"coverages" : ${#TestCase#coverages},
...

In this example, the script generates 2 coverages, but you can easily modify the `numOfCoverages` variable to reflect the actual number of coverages you need.